# map a values to a new index in array using php

Tags: php

i am trying to manipulate this array an get the values and re index the values i get

[click here for more detailed sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3S5NX.jpg)

```
  Array (
     [0] => Array
         (
           [0] => Array
                (
                    [test] => A
                )
        )
     [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [test] => B
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [test] => C
                )
        )
    )
```

**My Expected output**

```
Array (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [test] => A
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [test] => B
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [test] => C
            )
)
```

Comment: 1. No code on images. 2. Show us what have you tried to perform this manipulations.

Comment: `$result = array_column($arr, 0)`. Done!

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest its gives first element only

Comment: @AbdullaNilam, nope, you have missed the initial array structure. it'll return `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [test] => A
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [test] => B
        )

)`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest just tried it didnt get all of it

Comment: i update the array

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest  it didn't get all column indexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    foreach($array as $k => $v){
        if(is_array($v)){
            foreach($v as $m){
                $data[] = $m;
            }
        }
    }
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($data);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/aTt8s)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply  do

```
$data = $arrayName[0];
```

**Assume array is**

```
$arrayName = array(
    '0' => array(
        '0' => array(
            'test' => 'A'),
        '1' => array(
            'test' => 'B')
         ),
);
```

[**DEMO**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/tqy0-tzba)

Comment: how about if has two or more array indexes? i update the question above

Comment: for that, you have to use foreach and loop it. answered was based on your first question